# How can one .NET application require different .NET versions?

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks

I found an application that requires more than one .NET version.

```
**Requirements:**
.NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5 SP1 is required
```

So, how can **one** .NET application require more than one .NET framework?
Could somebody give an example how to write an application that requires more than one .NET framework?

Let´s say there are people who dont want to install 3 different .NET Frameworks, as I understood it would be enough to install just the highest one, that would work for 99% with all of the older .NET versions right? (So in this example, if we would have .NET 4.0 then the app should work?)

Comment: Where did you get these "requirements". Also, [this might be worth a read](http://superuser.com/questions/252614/do-i-need-all-microsoft-net-framework-versions)

Comment: Well, it is quite clumsy to write the requirements like that.  Installing all three versions does not in fact make sense, they overwrite each other.  They are not side-by-side versions like .NET 3.5 vs .NET 4.

It only needs *one* version, the last one.  Only install 3.5 SP1.  It includes the v2.0 and 3.0 assemblies.

Comment: I think If application you are building is interacting with some other dlls/project which may require other framework.